# How to use properties of optional object argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, optional-parameters

I have this code:

```
function getName(type, options) {

    if (type == 'dog') {
        var name = 'Rover';
    }
    else {
        var name = options.name || 'Buddy'
    }

    return name;
}
alert(getName('cat'));
```

I was expecting the `name` variable to be assigned to 'Buddy' but instead I got this error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Is there a simple way to handle this? I'm hoping for a one-line piece of code. I was thinking about using this but it seems long and unnecessarily complex:

```
var name = (options !== undefined && options.name) ? options.name : 'Buddy';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify the check to `options && options.name || 'Buddy'` because every object is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

Using optional parameters in es6 you can simply default it to an empty object so as not to deal with undefined.

```
function(type, options = {}) {
  return type === 'dog' ? 'Rover' : options.name || 'Buddy';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can defined a default value for the property of the argument using deconstruction (see [Setting a function parameter's default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)).
Adding `= {}` makes the whole argument optional, allowing for `getName('cat')` vs `getName('cat', {})`.

Note that you are not getting whole object passed as argument - just the properties you defined: `getName('bat', {somekey: 'I will not be passed to the function!'})`.

```js
function getName(type, {name = 'Buddy'} = {}) {
  if (type == 'dog') {
    name = 'Rover';
  }
  return name;
}
alert(`
cat: ${getName('cat')}, 
cat with name: ${getName('cat', {name: 'Puss'})}, 
dog: ${getName('dog')}, 
dog with name: ${getName('dog', {name: 'Spot'})}`);
```